# Read list of numbers in txt file and store to array C

Tags: c, arrays, file

I have a problem with reading the numbers. After I run the program everything is fine but there are no numbers in the array. I have tried different ways of writing the numbers in the file with no result.

```
FILE *myFile;
myFile = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
if (myFile==NULL)
{
    printf("Error Reading File\n");
}
else
{
tek=0;
for (i=0;i++)
{
//  tek=fgetc(myFile);
    fscanf(myFile,"%d",&tek);
    if (tek!=EOF)
    {
        redica[i]=tek;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
getch();
```

Comment: How is redica defined?

Comment: Note that `tek` doesn't contain EOF on EOF; the return value from `fscanf()` is EOF on EOF, or 0 when there's an error like a non-digit, non-space character in the input (e.g. a letter) — and 1 when the value is read successfully.  Check the value returned by `fscanf()`.

Comment: Also, there are many minor variants on this question on SO.  It's a duplicate for all intents and purposes — the difficulty is finding an appropriate question to duplicate it to.

Comment: And after how many iterations of main loop it breaks?

Comment: You would be more convincing if you posted compilable code.  You have your loop written as `for (i=0;i++)`.  Given that you say you have `int redica[50];`, you should have `for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)` for your loop.

Comment: My file has 8 numbers so it should break on the 9th

Comment: It is for (i = 0; i < 50; i++). I removed it by mistake

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following modification to your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int tek;
    int radica[50];

    // open file
    FILE *myFile = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
    // if opening file fails, print error message and exit 1
    if (myFile == NULL) {
        perror("Error: Failed to open file.");
        return 1;
    }

    // read values from file until EOF is returned by fscanf
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
        // assign the read value to variable (tek), and enter it in array (radica)
        if (fscanf(myFile, "%d", &tek) == 1) {
            radica[i] = tek;
        } else {
            // if EOF is returned by fscanf, or in case of error, break loop
            break; 
        }
    }

    // close file
    fclose(myFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Any number read by `fscanf` will be assigned to `tek`, and entered in the array `radica`, until fscanf returns `EOF`, at which point the loop breaks. As already mentioned, to determine when end of file is reached, it is not the variable `tek` that is compared to `EOF` but rather the return of `fscanf`.

Comment: The correct test is `if (fscnaf(myFile, "%d", &tek) == 1)`.  If there's a letter or a random punctuation character in the file, your code will go into a loop reading nothing useful until you reach the upper bound of the array.  It's good that you don't overflow the array; it's not good that you accept invalid data as valid.  (Unless the failure is before the first number is read, the last number read will be repeated until the end of the loop.)

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler, I've updated my post above. I guess it is a good idea not to assume that `numbers.txt` contains valid data only.

Comment: I see I have a typo in my previous comment — `fscnaf()` should be `fscanf()`, of course.  Yes, Murphy's Law applies to programming — if it can go wrong, it will.  Checking that the input worked is always important for robust programming.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue since "strcmp" only validated 7 characters (+1 that is the end of the string "\0"), I fixed the issue by using "strncmp", basically is the same function but it accepts as a third argument, the number of characters to be compared, in my case I used `strncmp(string1, string2, strlen(string1))` or change `strlen(string1)` with the number of characters you want to compare.